# datetime timezone order google sheets yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss GMT to dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss GMT

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets, time, timestamp

I have a Google sheet that needs timestamp in one column as is '2022-09-11 00:13:50 GMT' and in another column I need to convert to '11-09-2022 00:13:50 GMT'

I have tried:

1. copying cells into new column and reformatting but it isn't working
2. ```
   =datetime(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
   ```
3. ```
   =TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
   ```
4. ```
   =date(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
   ```
5. ```
   =Timestamp(A2,"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
   ```

Note the format column A is in is how it imports from another fixed sheet

I probably just too tired and missing the most obvious thing but I can't figure it out

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1alTL1z1ZXIr8rjF6hFHmJuD81OFK7TmqFdnC8ILIPwI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: with or without GMT on the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "(\d{4})-(\d+)-(\d+) (.+)", "$3/$2/$1 $4"))
```

[image]

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="",,REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, 
 "(\d{4})-(\d+)-(\d+) (.+) GMT", "$3/$2/$1 $4")*1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula in cell `D1`:

`=arrayformula( iferror( 1 / value( regexreplace(A1:A, " GMT", "") ) ^ -1 ) )`

Then format column `D` through **Format > Number > Custom date and time**.

Answer (score 0):

### Step 01

**Use this formula**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A1:A="",,DATEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,  "(.+?) "))+
                          TIMEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, " (.+?) "))))
```

[image]

### Step 02 - Format

[image]

### Result

[image]